# Discord Bot Command is not Showing

Tags: python, discord

So I'm making a basic bot command that responds with what the player said, like doing !test code will make the bot respond with 'code'. For some reason, nothing happens when the command is run. I even put a print inside of it to see if it was actually being run, and it wasn't. Here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    print("-"*16)

game = discord.Game("Discord")
await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(str(arg))

client.run('token here')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    print("-"*16)

game = discord.Game("Discord")
await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game)

@client.command()
async def test(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send(str(arg))

client.run('token here')
```

heres what you got wrong:

```
client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
```

You had 2 separate handlers for the bot, if you use commands you only need the `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")` line, in this case you had the bot handler for commands but you were running client

Comment: I would think the code above will throw an "'await' outside function" error ... did you test your answer

Comment: Yeah, it worked. I'm really confused, as theres only 2 changes: a variable name change and an asterick added. Also the await outside the function I added back in.

Comment: yeah ill edit the answer to show you what you did wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

The code below runs as expected when tested using Python3.7 ...

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    print("-"*16)

    game = discord.Game("Discord")
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game)

@client.command()
async def test(ctx, *arg):
    await ctx.send(str(arg))

client.run('token here')
```

Your code as posted has an await statement outside of a function

```
......
print("-"*16)

game = discord.Game("Discord")
await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game)
.......
```

Also change

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
```

TO:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *arg):
```

For an explanation as to why you pass `*arg` and not `arg`:

[args-and-kwargs](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/args-and-kwargs)

Answer (score 0):

You can't run client and bot together if want bot to run the last line of code must be bot.run('your token') if you want client to run use client.run('your token')